# Is it possible to pipe `script` to, for example, `xz` for on-the-fly compressing instead of a file or a device?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, on-the-fly, xz

The title is the question.

As `root`, I tried `script -a - | nice_xzfull file.xz` where `nice_xzfull`=`ionice -c 3 nice -n 20 xz -vvz9e --lzma2=dict=64MiB,mf=bt4,nice=273 --threads=3` (notice the last space) but instead `script` started and stopped, `xz` printed how the compressiong went, `script` stopping being evident by `exit` closing the SSH window instead of `script` closing and the `file.xz` being anywhere to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script` does not take `-` as standard output, thus your try failed. Fortunately, `bash` has the useful *process substitution* feature, which enables us to write

```
script >(nice_xzfull >file.xz)
```

(note the `>` before `file.xz`). The `script` option `-a` doesn't make sense here.